# What does 乃 mean here?

Tags: classical-chinese

On a particular forum is a banner reading:

> 此乃舊貼唯讀區

which I imagine is a highfalutin way of saying that this thread is read-only.

Now, 乃 has many senses in my dictionary. What is the sense of 乃 being used here? My best guess would be "only", in the sense that this page is "nothing more than" a read-only area.

Comment: 此 **乃** = This **is**, 舊貼 = old posts, 唯讀區 = read-only area.

Comment: From what I could read from the sentence it means the word "is" as mentioned by Stan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here "乃" means "be". This sentence means "This area is for old posts, and these posts are read-only."

Next time, if you find "此乃" these two characters together or a noun+乃 together, "乃" properly means "be". For example:

> 此乃我的书.
>    *This is my book.*
>
> 意识乃是大脑的一种自然属性。
>    *Consciousness is an emergent property of the brain.*

Comment: It should be emphasized that 乃 is an ancient expression in Chinese -- though it's occasionally used today, the whole sentence should be "of some old-style". To some extent, `此乃我的书` sounds a little funny/silly because 我的 is a modern expression. In a formal occasion, such a sentence will be criticized as 半文不白 (mixed style of classical and vernacular Chinese). However, compared with a single 乃, the compound verb `乃是` sounds *a limited little more* modern, so `意识乃是大脑的一种自然属性` is OK.

Comment: Stan you should make your own answer. I'd upvote you :)

Comment: 此乃我书, 的 is not required in the classical form.

Comment: @deutschZuid: such a complement to this answer would better be a comment so that visitors won't miss it. Earning reputations is fun, though :)

Answer (score -1):

In your giving sentence, it means is (be)

but as a chinese ,this verb is hardly use in communicating or writing, this is a verb which uses in ancient chinese

Comment: Disagree. 乃 is still very much in use in writing today.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is that you'd better have a Chinese dictionary when you learn it, for example <新华字典>. All the usual meaning will be presented with example. The 乃 in your example has the same meaning in the following example:吾乃常山赵子龙也from （三国演义）.